# Include function with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, path, include, handlebars.js

I have learned to use Handlebars.js in my HTML projects. I want to know, can I use "include function" from PHP in handlebars? For example:

PHP:

```
<?php include('path/to/file.html/php/etc.'); ?>
```

In handlebars something like this:

```
{{template.header}}
```

And in my JS file I can set the path to the header file.
Please tell me if this is possible and how I can do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is in the included PHP file and how does it affect your Handlebars template?

Comment: Are you talking about a partial? http://handlebarsjs.com/#partials

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible what you are asking.